# Jmeter - Selenium/Webdriver Support : HTMLUNIT driver error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, htmlunit-driver

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser name must be htmlunit
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.determineBrowserVersion(HtmlUnitDriver.java:315) ~[htmlunit-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:280) ~[htmlunit-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.HtmlUnitDriverConfig.createBrowser(HtmlUnitDriverConfig.java:21) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.HtmlUnitDriverConfig.createBrowser(HtmlUnitDriverConfig.java:8) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:676) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:644) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:632) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:246) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

2019-01-02 18:32:20,251 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:62) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
2019-01-02 18:32:20,251 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-01-02 18:32:20,252 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-01-02 18:32:20,252 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-01-02 18:32:20,253 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), I would suggest reaching out to [JMeter Plugins developers/maintainers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) and report the issue there.

---

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always use the latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.